# What is Taylor series??

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What is Taylor series? **Plz explain in simple words.** I need the proof for the series as well. What's the difference b/w Taylor series and Maclaurin series?
Any prerequisites needed to understand Taylor series better?
Thanks a ton in advance!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Better to look at Taylor polynomials first to get the insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One should first look up what a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) even is.  Then, you shall find this:

$$\text{Taylor series:}\\f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12f''(a)(x-a)^2+\dots\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

And a Maclaurin series is simply the Taylor series at $a=0$.  As far as notation goes, $f^{(n)}(a)$ is the $n$th derivative at $x=a$ and $n!=1\times2\times3\times\dots\times n$.  A visual representation was always intuitive for me:

The black is $\ln(x+1)$ and the colored line is $\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$.

[image]

Basically, you start with a point.  Then you draw the tangent line.  Then you draw... the quadratic line.  And so on.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "proof", since you probably meant "derivation", since a function is equal to its Taylor series only if it is analytic...